# getting cannot read properties of undefiend when fetching api in react

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I am working on an api and when I `console.log(data.city)` then it gives me result but if I add `console.log(data.city.name)` then it shows `undefined`. In console I'm getting the result but after reload this error came.
Also when first console is empty array and then second is data.

```
const [cityName, setCityName] = useState('delhi');
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);
  const getWeatherInfo = async () => {
    await fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=delhi&units=metric&appid=4beffc863037e89f0f181d893d1cf79b`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data)=> {
        setData(data)
      })
      .catch((err)=> {
        console.log('error' + err);
      })
  };

console.log(data.city.name);

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeatherInfo();
  }, []);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialising the state as an empty array, thereby the element `city` doesn't exist on the first render thus leading to an error.
You can fix this by logging only if the key city exists, as :

```
 if (data.city) {
    console.log(data.city.name);
  }
```

Comment: yes this is right, but i need more than one value as cards , so i think i can not use this method, do you have any other solution ?

Comment: @HowtoProgram `map` over the array and display it.

Comment: `need more than one value as cards` please explain this point like how you need to show this

Answer (score 1):

Why default state defined as array? As i can see there is no array in response, so it's better define default state as null.

```
const [data,setData] = useState(null);
```

And then you can use `?` instead of if statement

```
console.log(data?.city?.name);
```

Comment: Is there any way to get data in initial render?